# How to inject dispatch actions to props using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Im trying to create a simple project using `create-react-app-typescript`
First thing I wanted to set up was redux. So I did everything as normal, but now I have this problem I can't solve:

```
// src/App.tsx
interface AppProps {
  simpleAction: () => void;
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {
   ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction())
});
```

Everything looks ok, but when I call `App` like so

```
// index.tsx
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I get

```
[ts]  
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<AppProps, "simpleAction">, ComponentSta...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<AppProps, "simpleAction">>'.
    Property 'simpleAction' is missing in type '{}'.
```

So ts is expecting the action to be passed through props despite it's injected in connect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple:

```
interface IMapStateToProps {}

interface IMapDispatchToProps {
  simpleAction: () => void;
}

type AppProps = IMapStateToProps & IMapDispatchToProps;

class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {
...
}
...
...
...

export default connect<IMapStateToProps, IMapDispatchToProps, {}>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a demo app a while back that is based on create-react-app-typescript + redux. Have a look at [this container](https://github.com/stoepszli/clicker/blob/master/clicker-frontend/src/containers/Main.tsx) for an example of how to map a dispatch to a stateless component.

The pattern used in that repo above splits your components into a 'container' which maps all state and actions to props so the component can remain stateless and easy to test.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately it's no help, and if im being honest, the code is fairly messy

Comment: Did you try to refactor your code into the container/stateless component pattern? Btw, if redux AND typescript are new to you, learn one at a time. That is a steep learning curve with a lot of weird error messages ahead. Good luck!

Comment: Not new to me at all, just the first time I'm making my own boilerplate